# Using Scala and StringTemplate, how do I loop through a Map

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, stringtemplate

I have my environment setup nicely using Scala, StringTemplate within the Google AppEngine. I am having trouble looping through a Map and getting it to display in the template. When I assign a simple List of just Strings to the template it works using:

In Scala Servlet:

```
  var photos = List[String]()

  //... get photo url and title ...

  photos = photo_url :: photos
  template.setAttribute("photos", photos: _*)
```

In Template:

```
  $photos: { photo|
    <div><img src="$photo$_s.jpg"></div>
  }$
```

The above works. However, any attempt of creating a Map using url and title and assigning to the template gives me an error. Here is my attempt, which does not work:

In Scala Servlet:

```
  var photos = List[Map[String,String]]()

  //... get photo url and title ...

  photos = Map("url" -> url, "title" -> title) :: photos
  template.setAttribute("photos", photos: _*)
```

In Template:

```
  $photos: { photo|
    <div><img src="$photo.url$_s.jpg" title="$photo.title$"></div>
  }$
```

This gives me the following error

```
Class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2 has no such attribute: title in template context
```

Thoughts / Ideas ?

Comment: Deleted my suggestion--I'm just remarking here that my simple idea of creating `case class TitleURL(url: String, title: String)` and using that instead of the map does not work. According to Marcus, it generates an error like "Class FlickrTestServlet$TitleURL$2 has no such attribute: title in template context [templates/flickr_template if(photos)_subtemplate anonymous]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on Rex's suggestion, I was able to make it work using a case class with a `@BeanProperty` annotation for the fields:

```
case class MyPhoto(@BeanProperty val url: String, @BeanProperty val title: String)

def generateMyPhotos() : String = {
  val tp = new StringTemplate("$photos: { photo|<div><img src=\"$photo.url$_s.jpg\"  title=\"$photo.title$\"></div>}$")
  val photos = List(MyPhoto("http://myphoto.com", "my photo"))
  tp.setAttribute("photos", photos: _*)
  tp.toString
}
```

This worked for me (using the [scalasti](http://bmc.github.com/scalasti/) library for StringTemplate, as you probably also already did).

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you!!  Yep, I am using scalasti wrapper for StringTemplate. The only thing I had to do was add an import for Bean Property  import scala.reflect._

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple alternative, without using additional packages and annotations. Register a scala object adaptor that knows how to retrieve property values from scala objects and scala collections.

This is now included in the StringTemplate FAQ at:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Altering+property+lookup+for+Scala